# Trying to autosize grid on tab control to fill the right side, but has a border around it

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to dock the grid to fill in the whole right side of the form, but it is not docking regardless of me using stretch.

[image: You should have put an image description here...]

Code I am using:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TabStripPlacement="Left" Background="#FF374E5A" BorderBrush="#FF374E5A" Foreground="#FF374E5A" SelectionChanged="tabControl_SelectionChanged" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem" Foreground="#FF374E5A" BorderBrush="#FF374E5A" Background="#FF374E5A" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle1}">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem" BorderBrush="#FF374E5A" Foreground="#FF374E5A" Background="#FF374E5A" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle2}">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-2,0,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="53*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

How can I fix this so the left side is the tabs(color) and the right side is the gray grid with no blue around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TabControl has a default padding value.You Should Set it "0" Like This;

Padding="0"

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TabStripPlacement="Left" Background="#FF374E5A" BorderBrush="#FF374E5A" Foreground="#FF374E5A" SelectionChanged="tabControl_SelectionChanged" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TabItem Header="TabItem" Foreground="#FF374E5A" BorderBrush="#FF374E5A" Background="#FF374E5A" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle1}">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem" BorderBrush="#FF374E5A" Foreground="#FF374E5A" Background="#FF374E5A" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle2}">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-2,0,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="12*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="53*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to -1 instead because there was still a tine blue line around but that fixed it :)